# Mysql time type returns wrong in symfony DateTime type

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

I have an property of time type in my Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="time")
 */
protected $max_time;
```

But in my twig template, it returns a object of DateTime type with an wrong value:

```
DateTime {#698 ▼
  +"date": "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "America/Sao_Paulo"
}
```

In database the value of this data is 03:00:00

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you set your locale? [`date_default_timezone_set `](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).  If you need to adjust what is stored see: `setTimezone`.  You need to know the value you are storing.  Then it should be trivial.

Comment: Yes, I set my locale. But I don't what to store a date in specific, I only what to store a time. 01:00:00, 02:00:00, 03:23:00

Comment: Ahh, you are getting unix epoch.  Pretty sure Doctrine will always return a `\DateTime` object... `time: Type that maps a SQL TIME to a PHP DateTime object`.  Up to you to format it.  What is type in your database?

Comment: In the database the type of column is time too.

Comment: I only use `timestamp` and `datetime`.  Could it simply be that the date part is epoch while the time part is actually correct?  Change in DB to 03:10:00.  What comes back?

Comment: If I convert to timestap, returns it: Could not convert database value "0000-00-00 00:00:00" to Doctrine Type time. Expected format: H:i:s

If I leave the column as time and set to 03:10:00, returns: "1970-01-01 00:00:00"

Comment: Hmm.  I can only suggest workarounds.  Like use an int type if representing an interval or offset.  I find database types `int`, `datetime`, and `timestamp` serve all my needs for date and time.    Added Doctrine2 tag, can see if later someone can shed more light.

Comment: I'll to this. Thank you.

Comment: Could come down to abstraction.  RDBMS handle dates rather differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went and tried to replicate this to provide a valuable answer. However you have provided very limited information on how you got to this. What error you're receiving and so on... so I'm going to post what I did and it's results.

I've unfortunately found no issue. The error I got at first was it was unable to convert DateTime to string. Once I added the `date` filter it stopped causing an error.

Entity

```
/**
 * @var DateTime
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="time", type="time")
 */
private $time;
```

Stored in Table

```
mysql> select * from Product;
+----+----------+-----------+-------+----------------+----------+
| id | owner_id | name      | price | description    | time     |
+----+----------+-----------+-------+----------------+----------+
|  1 |        1 | Prod Name | 2.123 | WHat happened? | 11:21:00 |
+----+----------+-----------+-------+----------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Twig Template

```
    <table id="example">
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</ht>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for product in products %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.time|date('H:i:s') }}{{ dump(product.time) }}</td>
                <td>{% if is_granted('EDIT', product) %}
                    <a href="{{ path('app_product_show', {'id': product.id}) }}" class="btn btn-sm">Edit</a>
                {% endif %}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Rendered

[Twig Rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bRiM.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you add annotation `@ORM\Column(type="time")` to entity property in database (tested in MySQL) field of type "Time" will be created to store values like '00:00:00'. When doctrine fetch you entity it converts Time from database to PHP DateTime object [reference](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#time)

So to get time from this object just format it `$entity->getTimeField()->format('H:i:s');`

And don't forget that it should be real time value like '21:19:00' not some time lenght, ex '45:00:12'